# Common tests for impure functions in a package R

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, r-package

A pure function is a function where the return value is only determined by its input values, without observable side effects.

What are some of the ways you can catch impure functions in R programatically?

- I often do `lsf.str("package:base")` (using `base` as an example here) when exploring a package.
- I also try and walk through the source to see if/where there are calls to functions I know to be im-pure.
- I will tend to run the examples given in a function's documentation many times and test the result for equality: eg. `is.recursive(replicate(10, 1+2))`

This is both not very time consuming and I'm sure there's a set of better/more robust ways to explore which functions are impure.

So what are common/robust tests for impure functions in an R package ?

<s>- best practise tangent (*feel free to ignore*): Also, if you have an impure function, should you document it explicitly under its `?`</s>

N.B. I'm just looking for common checklist type things people might use not something which will always catch all the cases (as this may not even be possible.._

Comment: This sounds computationally impossible for any general function (equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) especially since R functions can behave very differently based on input. Why do you need to be able to do such detection?

Comment: Take a look at [checkUsage](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/codetools/functions/checkUsage) from the `codetools` package.

Comment: Do you consider `runif()` to be pure or impure?

Comment: @Gregor i tend to think of it as impure since I cannot predict the exact output from the input BUT I can predict the _structure_ of the output based on the input so it's not so bad. Any function that calls `runif()` is impure because it injects un-predictable behaviour? thoughts?

Comment: @MrFlick Very true I do get this; I'm just wondering practically here.. Say a solution where most of the time I would programmatically catch obvious cases.

Comment: @Dason But then it has the side effect of changing the seed! @ anamnesis As far as your your best practise tangent, certainly you should not ask people to document impure functions explicitly---lots of work for almost no tangible benefit. That said, I think it is good practice to document side effects.

Comment: I'd also recommend taking the best practice bit out of the question, it falls under "primarily opinion based", and if there's much more discussion it should probably move to chat.

Comment: @Dason updated to strikeout!

Comment: Wikipedia suggests this isn't a "worldwide" definition.  You may want to categorize as "doesn't change global objects via `<<-` or other tools"  ; "doesn't depend on any PRNG";  and maybe "doesn't depend on any called functions which might change,"  tho' that last one is basically impossible to meet in practice.